# Direcionar para respositório do github

Tags: git, github

Existe um repositório no github onde ja contém um projeto. Eu tenho que criar um branch novo e colocar o meu próprio projeto la, porém, não sei como eu direciono para o repositório, e além disso, para um branch certo, alguém pode me mostrar os passos para resolver isso ?

Comment: Tu vai precisar fazer o checkout do repositório e ele vai sobrescrever tudo, só depois disso tu muda o branch e aí coloca os seus arquivos. Qualquer outra coisa que tu tentar além disso tu vai perder os arquivos.

Comment: Pois é, não posso perder os arquivos que estão no master, teria que ir direto para um branch novo

Comment: Você vai ter dois projetos de código no mesmo repositório, é isso? Eles são dependentes? Por que precisam estar no mesmo repositório? Depois você irá fazer um merge para a branch master?

Comment: Existe um projeto no master com um objetivo, eu criei um projeto diferente, porém com mesmo objetivo, portanto, me foi dito para colocar no mesmo repositório, porém, enquanto não estiver finalizado, ser colocado em um branch diferente.